# How do I print the label text in Haskell GI-Gtk listBoxRow?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to print the label text when I click on a listBoxRow.

This is the link to my gist: https://gist.github.com/bigos/6cf02ff27231cfc0352394da00023f67

the relevant code looks like this:

```
  _ <- onListBoxRowSelected listbox2 (\(Just r) -> do
                                        -- rn <- listBoxRowGetIndex r
                                        cc <- containerGetChildren r
                                        dd <- widgetGetName (head cc)
                                        -- how do I print label text?
                                        -- I get the error:
                                        -- Required ancestor ‘GI.Gtk.Objects.Label.Label’ not found for type GI.Gtk.Objects.Widget.Widget’.
                                        ee <- labelGetText (head cc)
                                        putStrLn ("Clicked " ++ (show ee)))
```

### The error

> • Required ancestor ‘GI.Gtk.Objects.Label.Label’ not found for type
>   ‘GI.Gtk.Objects.Widget.Widget’. • In a stmt of a 'do' block: ee <-
>   labelGetText (head cc)   In the expression:
>       do { cc <- containerGetChildren r;
>            ee <- labelGetText (head cc);
>            putStrLn ("Clicked " ++ (show ee)) }   In the second argument of ‘onListBoxRowSelected’, namely

### relevant documentation

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gi-gtk-3.0.18/docs/doc-index.html

Answer (score 0):

Dan Robertson has provided the most helpful answer. After obtaining the label object you have to cast it to Label type. That was the missing link.

### working code

```
  _ <- onListBoxRowSelected listbox2 (\(Just r) -> do
                                         cc <- containerGetChildren r
                                         mlabel <- castTo Label (head cc)
                                         case mlabel of
                                           Nothing -> putStrLn "Not a label!"
                                           Just label -> (labelGetText label) >>= putStrLn . unpack)
```

Thank you very much for your help.

related post
[How do I cast Widget to Label in Haskell's GI-Gtk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47979509/how-do-i-cast-widget-to-label-in-haskells-gi-gtk)