# How do I cast Widget to Label in Haskell's GI-Gtk?

Tags: haskell, gtk3

I have this sample code where I have a ListBox containing ListBoxRows, which in turn contain a Label. When I click on the ListBox, I get a ListBoxRow. So far so good. The problems start when I want to interact with the ListBoxRows children.

I have used this function to get the Label, which is the child of the ListBoxRow.
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gi-gtk-3.0.18/docs/GI-Gtk-Objects-Container.html#g:13

However, the returned type is Widget. How do I convert the type of the object? Function widgetGetName tells me it is a label, but the Haskell Type system insists it is a Widget, so I can not use label specific functions.

### working code

```
  _ <- onListBoxRowSelected listbox2 (\(Just r) -> do
                                         cc <- containerGetChildren r
                                         mlabel <- castTo Label (head cc)
                                         case mlabel of
                                           Nothing -> putStrLn "Not a label!"
                                           Just label -> (labelGetText label) >>= putStrLn . unpack)
```

Thanks to Dan

Comment: Could you please provide a short Haskell example which clearly illustrates the problem and what you want to do.

Comment: Have you tried using [`castTo`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-gi-base-0.20.7/docs/Data-GI-Base-ManagedPtr.html#v:castTo)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cc <- containerGetChildren r
mlabel <- castTo Label (head cc)
case mlabel of
  Nothing -> putStrLn “Not a label!”
  Just label -> labelGetText label >>= putStrLn
```

Comment: getting close:  Couldn't match type ‘Text’ with ‘[Char]’
  Expected type: Text -> IO ()
    Actual type: String -> IO ()

Comment: Apologies. You need to convert text to string or print text. But you’ve figured that out I see